# Visual Studio: Cycle Clipboard Ring stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

The Cycle Clipboard Ring feature in Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working correctly. It has begun to simply paste the latest item on the clipboard.

This is not because the `CTRL+SHIFT+V` shortcut was hijacked. If I go through `EDIT -> Cycle Clipboard Ring`, the very same thing happens.

I don't have ReSharper installed.

How did this happen, and how do I get the clipboard ring back?